# AddTo operation to random element of a list yields unexpected results

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of numbers. I want to randomly select one of those, with a probability proportional to its value, and increment it by one.

I tried this simple one-liner

```
my_list = {1,1,1}
my_list[[RandomSample[my_list->Range[Length[my_list]]]] += 1
```

and it works just fine as long as the elements of my_list are all identical. However, when my_list contains values that are not all identical, sometimes it fails spectacularly, e.g.:

```
SeedRandom[1]
my_list = {1,2,3}
my_list[[RandomSample[my_list->Range[Length[my_list]]]] += 1
{4,2,3}
```

My guess is that for some reason here RandomSample is called twice, once for deciding which number from my list is incremented by 1 and then another time to decide where to store the result of the operation. So in the above example first the number 3 is incremented by 1, and then the result is stored in position 1.

If this is the case, is this an expected behaviour? If not, can you explain it?

P.s. There is of course a trivial workaround, i.e. to store the result of RandomSample in a temporary variable and use that to index my_list. But here I would like to understand what is happening exactly in my one-liner.

P.p.s: to put things in perspective, the same thing e.g. in python would just work, that's why I am particularly puzzled:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([1,2,3])
my_list[np.random.choice([0,1,2], p=my_list/my_list.sum())] += 1
```

Comment: `mylist[[First@RandomSample[mylist -> Range[Length[mylist]], 1]]] += 1`

Don't use underscores in simple symbol names, for one: these have meaning. Secondly, you need to provide a scalar (`First@...`).

Comment: RandomSample here already yields a scalar, your code leaves mylist unchanged

Comment: No, `RandomSample[mylist -> Range[Length[mylist]]]` yields a sample of 3, in essence sorted by weights. You must specify a count/use first.

In any case, this is not python, and the evaluation rules used are such that using direct increment on an array with a random target within is a bad idea, and bad coding practice IMO. Much clearer to obtain the target index, *then* increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mylist +=  UnitVector[Length@mylist,  RandomChoice[mylist -> Range@Length@mylist]]`

will accomplish your apparent goal without the issues you've displayed.

As to your secondary questions of

> "If this is the case, is this an expected behaviour? If not, can you
> explain it?"

it is right there in the documentation, the very first line of the details:

> x+=dx is equivalent to x=x+dx